# returning a datatable and hash from wcf service

Tags: vb.net, wcf, datatables

We have a web service that retrieve lookup information then returns a datatable to the user.  We also wanted to create a hash of the datatable and return it along with the datatable.  Since i can only return one item at a time from the web service what would be the easiest way i can return both.  I don't want to create a list or class instead i want the datatable.  and i'm not sure i want to include the hash in the datatable ... 
right now i have a call to retrieve the datatable. then i make another call again to get the hash and then i compare later if its correct. I do this to verify data integrity just wondering if theres a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Your method would have to return a class object that has both properties. The service will create a new `TableWithHash` object and fill the properties and return this class instance.

```
Public Class TableWithHash
  Public Property myTable As DataTable
  Public Property myHash As String
End Class
```